# Simple toggle div visibility with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, css

This is very frustrating as it seems so simple yet is not working.

In my body I have

```
<div id ="splashscreen" style="display:block">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p>text</p>
    <inputtype="button" value="Start" onClick="splash();" />
</div>`
```

And in my head, within script tags I have

```
function splash() {
    var divSplash = document.getElementById("splashscreen");
    divSplash.style.display = "none";
}
```

Surely when Start button is clicked, the `splash()` function should be called and the display of my `splashscreen` div be chanted to none?

Comment: spashscreen = splashscreen? Really? No wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: Please elaborate. I'm pretty tired so more than likely made a silly mistake!

Comment: woops that was just a typo when trying to format the code for Stack

Comment: So issue is solved? It was easy one!

Comment: no, the typo wasn't in my original code so the issue remains

Comment: do you have more then one element in the page with the same id maybe? because this code by itself works. u probably have a error somewhere else in the page

Comment: Would you post your script tag signature? Is it <script type="text/javascript">?

Comment: Something is missing here, there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: it was just 'javascript' but having changed it, the issue remains. Is there a console in the Palemoon/Firefox browser or any other way of debugging?

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+J` opens a console in Firefox.

Comment: please paste more code. it must have something to do with the order of your code

Comment: I've downloaded Palemoon, tested and works as expected.

Comment: Here is my full code
`<html>
<head>
<script language="text/javascript">
function startGame()
{
 var divSplash = document.getElementById("splash");
 divSplash.style.display = "none"; 
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id ="splash" style="display:block"><h3>Test</h3><p>Blah blah</p><input type="button" value="Start" onClick="startGame();" /></div>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: change `language="text/javascript"` to `type="text/javascript"` it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the you write `language="text/javascript"`, if you use instead `language="javascript"` it works.

I recommend you remove the language property and use **type="text/javascript"** instead. If you're using HTML5, [you can omit the type property](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/script.html).

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function startGame() { 
        var divSplash = document.getElementById("splash"); 
        divSplash.style.display = "none"; 
    } 
</script>
```

Also, the language property [is now obsolete](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html).

Comment: is there a reason the sample code I was learning from worked fine, despite having `language`?

Comment: @user1765369 Does it have a DOCTYPE declared?

Comment: I've tested in all major browsers with language="text/javascript". Neither of them work. Are you sure it wasn't language="javascript"?

Comment: Ah yes, somewhere in all the chopping and changing it got mixed up. If only my lecturer had bothered to use valid code in his examples!

Answer (score 1):

Using the exact code that you show here, I get the error 'divSplash is null.' This is to be expected -- your div is named "spashscreen" but your JS function is looking for a div named "splashscreen." (You're missing an 'l').

When I fix the typo, it works.

Comment: Like I said, it works for me when I fix the typo. It must be somewhere else in your code? Try using the Firefox Web Console and see what error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the same id :)

spashscreen != splashscreen

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJVvw/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id ="splashscreen" style="display:block">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p>text</p>
    <button onclick="splash()">Start</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function splash() {
    var divSplash = document.getElementById('splashscreen');
    divSplash.style.display = "none";
}
```